# Exclude unused locales momentjs using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, momentjs

I am trying to exclude unused momentjs locales using webpack.
I have tried both 3 ways below:

1- moment-locales-webpack-plugin

```
new MomentLocalesPlugin({
    localesToKeep: ["en"]
  })
```

2- ContextReplacementPlugin

```
 new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/)
```

3- ignorePlugin

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(
  /^\.\/locale$/,
  /moment$/
});
```

But, none of these methods work for me and all locales still exist in final bundle. My webpack version is 4.28.2. And I am using moment-js v 2.23.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2517#issuecomment-393704231

Comment: @SergeK. That's my first solution.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/)
> ```

There is no 'en' locale in moment.js; that's why it loads all of them. Try `/en-gb/` if you need only English.